# Move JFrame for right display of JCombobox

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, jcombobox

I've programmed a JFrame, that adds a JPanel and this adds my JCombobox.
My problem is, that the JCombobox won't be displayed right until I change the size of my frame.

Here is my code:

```
    /* JFrame */
    frame = new JFrame("Frame");
    frame.setBounds(0, 0, 900, 800);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    /* JPanels */
    panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBounds(frame.getBounds());
    panel.setVisible(true);
    panel.setLayout(null);
    panel.addMouseListener(m);

    /* JComboBox */
    String comboBoxListe[] = { "1", "2", "3" };
    JComboBox chooser = new JComboBox(comboBoxListe);
    chooser.setSize(200, 25);
    chooser.setLocation(30, 30);
    chooser.setVisible(true);

    panel.add(chooser);
    frame.add(panel);
```

Can someone see what I did wrong?
Thanks for your help :)

Comment: What version of Java are you using? The same code seems to be working fine. Looks like there is more to the problem than what you have presented.

Comment: what do you think could be another problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `JFrame` was made visible before the combo box was added

```
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Ensure this appears *after* the component is added

Swing was designed for [layout managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) to be used - use one here

Comment: +1 Since I think the setVisible is causing the problem. But also for recommending the use of layout managers as that is really the underlying problem here.

Comment: Thanks it worked fine. 
BUT I thought that would work fine too with a frame.repaint() and I have one(not posted here).
And I'm using a layoutmanager...

Comment: @InformatikBabo, `BUT I thought that would work fine too with a frame.repaint()` - any time you add/remove components to a visible GUI you need to invoke revalidate() (to invoke the layout manager)and then repaint() (to paint the components at their new size/location). You only need to do this on the panel that change, not the frame.